# Dynamic passing of parameters from one http API call to other http call in golang

Tags: go, http, struct, https

I have to make two HTTP API calls in GoLang, the first API call returns this JSON response:

```json
{
  "key": "<some value>",
  "msg": "OK"
}
```

My JSON struct for first response is setup like this:

```
type One struct {
    key   string `json:"key"`
    msg    string `json:"msg"`
}
```

The second call is where I'm struggling with. As you can see the first API call returns a `result -> key`. This key value should be the in parameter for my second call/struct, but I can't seem to figure how to make it dynamic. This key will always change based on the first API call. I have no way currently to parse the second call's JSON and setup my struct. On the second API call I want to access the remote URL using the key value from one first API call.

Second call result :

```json
{
  "key": "<value from first API call>",
  "content": "24"
}
```

Does anyone know how to setup my struct or go about this? I am a new programmer in Go and decided to ask for some help.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck? You show JSON and Go structs but no code whatsoever. Handling JSON is simple in Go and the official documentation (and the Internets) is full of workable examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the second API based on the result of the first API, you will need something like this:

```
type One struct {
    Key   string `json:"key"`
    Msg    string `json:"msg"`
}

// first api call
res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

r := &io.LimitedReader{
    R: res.Body,
    N: 2 << 10,
}

var first One
d := json.NewDecoder(r)
if err := d.Decode(&first); err != nil && err != io.EOF {
    // handle error
}

type Two struct {
    Key string `json:"key"`
    Content string `json:"content"`
}

// second API call
second := Two {
     Key: first.Key
     Content: "[YourContentHere]"
}

body, err := json.Marshal(second)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, targetURL, body)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// replace httpClient with your client
res, err := httpClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

If you need to put the key in the URL instead of request body:

```
targetURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://some.domain/path/with/%s/key", first.Key)
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, targetURL, nil)
```

Comment: what is the below doing? Also how can we parse the json response of the first api call to pass in for second?                                                                                                       
    responsr := &io.LimitedReader{
    R: res.Body,
    N: 2 << 10,

Comment: @Sri I missed the decoder line (`d := json.NewDecoder(r)`) and updated the answer. `res.Body` holds the API response, wrapping it with `LimitedReader{}` helps deal with large responses by limiting the max response size to 2048 bytes (2 << 10) in our application. If you trust the API you can pass res.Body directly to `json.NewDecoder(res.Body)`. `d.Decode(&first)`  parses the response body (json here) to the `first` variable. Then key can be accessed using `first.Key`

Comment: How do we pass res.Body directly to json.NewDecoder(res.Body)? Sorry, I'm fairly new programming with go. How do we pass http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ into the code line res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)?

Comment: @Sri just by `json.NewDecoder(res.Body)` you're passing res.Body directly to the json decoder.

Comment: tHow do we pass https://pokeapi.co/api/v2 into the code line res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)?

Comment: Is their any way we store the key value in memory and pass as header to the second api call?

Comment: You have defined "body" in your code, but where is it being used?